# Create more than one row in a for-each loop

Tags: c#, ado.net

Working on an old application I see this code:, It is using `DataTable`, `DataRow` stuff.

```
foreach (string networkIdToCreate in networkIdsToCreate)
{
    HTExtractSchema.HTProviderMedicalGroupContractRow rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract = tblHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.NewHTProviderMedicalGroupContractRow();
    rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.ItemArray = rHTProviderMedicalGroupContractDefaults.ItemArray;
    rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.NetworkId = networkIdToCreate;
    rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.Business = "470";
    tblHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.Rows.Add(rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract);
}
```

So it creates the new row, puts some values in there and adds it to the `DataTable`.

Now I want to modify it to create two rows instead of one row, all values the same except for "`Business`" field, it is one line before the last in the code above.

So I did that like this:

```
foreach (string networkIdToCreate in networkIdsToCreate)
{
    HTExtractSchema.HTProviderMedicalGroupContractRow rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract = tblHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.NewHTProviderMedicalGroupContractRow();
    rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.ItemArray = rHTProviderMedicalGroupContractDefaults.ItemArray;
    rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.NetworkId = networkIdToCreate;
    rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.Business = "470";
    tblHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.Rows.Add(rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract);

    HTExtractSchema.HTProviderMedicalGroupContractRow rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract2 = tblHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.NewHTProviderMedicalGroupContractRow();
    rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract2.ItemArray = rHTProviderMedicalGroupContractDefaults.ItemArray;
    rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract2.NetworkId = networkIdToCreate;
    rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract2.Business = "475";
    tblHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.Rows.Add(rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract2);
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a better way other than this copy paste? so if someone saw the code won't laugh at me :D

Comment: Just wrap your row creation code in method.

Comment: You can turn that into a method, or you can have an internal loop that will run twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this internal loop

```
foreach(var business in new[] {"470", "475"})
{
    ...
    rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.Business = business ;
    ...
}
```

EDIT

Or you can use a method

```
private void CreatRow(
    string networkIdToCreate,
    string business)
{
    HTExtractSchema.HTProviderMedicalGroupContractRow rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract = 
        tblHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.NewHTProviderMedicalGroupContractRow();
    rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.ItemArray = 
        rHTProviderMedicalGroupContractDefaults.ItemArray;
    rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.NetworkId = networkIdToCreate;
    rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.Business = business;
    tblHTProviderMedicalGroupContract.Rows.Add(rHTProviderMedicalGroupContract);
}
```

and use it like this

```
foreach (string networkIdToCreate in networkIdsToCreate)
{
    CreatRow(networkIdToCreate, "470");
    CreatRow(networkIdToCreate, "475");
    if(networkIdToCreate == "2" || networkIdToCreate == "6")
    {
        CreateRow(networkIdToCreate, "474");
    }
}
```

Note you may need to pass in `tblHTProviderMedicalGroupContract` depending on its scope,

Comment: I have one more condition too: IF networkIdToCreate  is equal to 2 or 6, then also create a business with number "474" ..but 470 and 475 always get created regardless

Comment: @ConfusedSleepyDeveloper In that case I'd suggest a method.  I'll update my answer.